# Merge list values inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge, iteration

I have to solve something that would be quite simple for me in PHP, but I'm missing it about how to do it in Python.

Suppose I have the following dictionary:

```
data = {'year': [], 'week': [], 'value': []}
```

all lists will have always same length, so a possible value of data would be:

```
{'year': ['2014', '2014', '2014'], 'week': ['44', '49', '49'], 'value': [15, 20, 30]}
```

**What I'm trying to do:**

When iterating the list 'week' :

· If current week has the same value than the next one in the list:

·· Overwrite that week with the next one, overwrite the year with next one, and sum the values with same indexes than the week.

**What I expect to obtain:**

So result would be:

```
{'year': ['2014', '2014'], 'week': ['44', '49'], 'value': [15, 50]}
```

**What I've tried:**

· Iterating over the dictionary, but but my poor knowledge of python, I've obtained errors such as `object of type 'bool' has no len()` when trying to build a `for` loop. (I've used constructs `for i in range len(dictionary.index)`)

· Checked out `itertools` and `collections`, but I'm not able to find anything that suits.

· Trying it out in a step-by step simple way: dumpling lists from the dictionary into another list and then compare items one by one, saving values into another list, etcetera.

Any ideas or documentation to check? (apart from keep learning python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby` and iterate over `enumerate(d['week'])`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

d = {'year': ['2014', '2014', '2014'], 'week': ['44', '49', '49'], 'value': [15, 20, 30]}
out = {'year': [], 'week': [], 'value': []}

for k, g in groupby(enumerate(d['week']), key=itemgetter(1)):
    total = 0
    for i, x in g:
        total += d['value'][i]
    # Now `i` is the last index of the group and `x` is the last week of the group,
    # We can use these to get values from 'year' and 'week'.
    out['year'].append(d['year'][i])
    out['week'].append(x)
    out['value'].append(total)

print out
#{'week': ['44', '49'], 'value': [15, 50], 'year': ['2014', '2014']}
```

Comment: Fantastic, I checked out `groupby` but `enumerate` was the thing I was missing about how use it inside an index, among other things...
Also, it's a sweet 'pythonic' way
TFYH